# Match resulting String using regex

Tags: .net, regex

I have a string `00408-B193AQ-P-DW-11045` which is a TAG of Pipe. Using regex I want to match only `B193AQ-DW-11045`.Using global option I am able to get the required using regex `[A-Z][0-9a-zA-Z][^P]+`. But ours system supports ignore case (not global). So with ignore case need a regex which gives the required result.

Comment: Which programming language or environment are you writing this in?

Comment: "our system supports ignore case (not global)" this part is not clear.  Can the input be upper or lowercase?  Why do you care whether case insensitivity is global or not?  Anyway, this particular feature is highly dependent on what programming language and/or regex library you are using. Your question can't be answered without that information.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the regex doesn't do what you think it does. Could you clarify what *exactly* the rules are for matching/not matching?

Answer (score 0):

If You check programmatically You could broke into named groups:

```
(?'index'[\d]{5})-(?'index1'[0-9a-zA-Z]{6})-(?'index3'[A-Z])-(?'index4'[A-Z]{2})-(?'index5'[0-9]{5})
```

Returns:

```
index: 00408
index1: B193AQ
index3: P
index4: DW
index5: 11045
```

If just check for matching some of parts try use this pattern:

```
.{5}-([0-9a-zA-Z]{6})-.-([A-Z]{2})-([0-9]{5})
```

Here '.' (dot) means any character